# Extending Jython Syntax

Tags: python, jython, dsl

I would like to add syntax to Jython to enable a nicer API for users. For instance, matrix libraries like NumPy would benefit from having both matrix and elementwise operations like Matlab's `:*` vs. `*` infix operators.

You can create a matrix in Octave using:

```
A = [ 1, 1, 2; 3, 5, 8; 13, 21, 34 ]
```

which is considerably nicer than NumPy's:

```
b = array( [ (1.5,2,3), (4,5,6) ] )
```

`R` uses formulas "y ~ x + z" for selecting variables in a matrix/data frame.  This is considerably nicer than the alternative of `["y"] ["x","z"]` or parsing the string "y ~ x + y".

More complicated examples can be implemented in Cython using [Easy Extend](http://www.fiber-space.de/EasyExtend/doc/EE.html). But EasyExtend doesn't work on the JVM.

What is the easiest way but reasonably robust way to add syntax to Jython?  It would be nice to have a framework to implement entirely new language constructs or define mini languages within jython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is not a macro / syntax expanding facility similar to EasyExtend, although [the developer of EasyExtend](http://fiber-space.de/wordpress/) has been working on some jython projects recently (including some which are similar to EE).  I suppose you could write a preprocessor of some kind, but I would tend to suggest that syntax extension isn't terribly popular in the python world and you might have better success implementing your own DSL if you really need to.